# How do you add a check in a Laravel model to prevent deletion?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

How do you add a check in a Laravel model to prevent deletion of any rows in a database?

(Using Laravel 5.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overwrite the delete() method in the model to return false if a check fails. It could look like this:

```
public function delete(){
    $check = true;
    if ($check == true){
        parent::delete();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course, `$check` will always be `true` in this example, but you can replace that with your own logic.

Comment: Ah thank you! So just returning false will do the trick?

Comment: That would prevent anything in the model from ever being deleted, yes.

Comment: Awesome thanks!!! As soon it will let me will accept the answer. Thank you :-D